# Upsert-Updating multiple fields of a document including lists and nested lists using pyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a collection with documents like this:

```
{
"_id"    : "1234567890",
"area"   : "Zone 63",
"last_state" : "Cloudy",
"recent_indices" : [
        21,
        18,
        33,
        ...
        38
        41
  ],

"Report_stats" : [
 {
        "date_hour" : "2017-01-01 01",
        "count"     : 31
     },
 {
        "date_hour" : "2017-01-01 02",
        "count"     : 20
     },
        ...
     {
        "date_hour" : "2018-08-26 13",
        "count"     : 3
     }     
  ]
}
```

which is supposed to be updated based on some online real-time reports
and assume each report looks like this:

```
{
 'datetime' : '2018-08-26 13:48:11.677635',
 'areas'    : 'Zone 3; Zone 45; Zone 63',
 'status'   : 'Clear',
 'index'    : '33'
 }
```

Now I have to update the collection in way that:

1. Each time that a new 'area' (say Zone 1025) shows up on the report, a new document adds to keep the related data
2. New 'index' adds to list "recent_indices" while "last_state" updates to 'status'
3. based on what the 'datetime' is, the respective "Report_stats.count" increments by 1 or a new "Report_stats" document ('datetime' with an hour resolution, where its 'count' is 1) inserted.

The way to do each of these updates separately, is somehow obvious, the problem is: How can I do all these simultaneously in a single update/upsert task?

I tried to use `update_one` and `find_one_and_update`(as well as `update` and `find_and_modify`) using pyMongo, but it was not possible (for me at least) to resolve the problem.

So I started to wonder if there possibly is a simple/single task to do so, or I should start trying to fix it in a different way altogether.

Can you please help me how to do this or (since there is a lot of data being gathered and therefore should be processed) suggest a low-cost alternative?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if I understand your question, but if your problem revolves around upsert i.e update it or add the record if it is not there.
You can do it by adding one parameter like this:

```
update_one( {'_id':1}, {$set:{}}, upsert=True )
```

If you want to update multiple fields you can simply do it like setting your updated document:

```
{
    name: 'Kanika',
    age: 19
},
//set document
{
    name: 'Andy',
    age: 30
}
```

Please try looking into: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/ , if it helps.

Thanks, Kanika

Comment: Obviously, I know what upsert is. As I noted, I have tried what you're suggesting, but the problem is the structure of the document which should be updated in the way I explained. However thank, you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have reached so far, is this:

```
if mycollection.find_one({'area': 'zone 45', 'Report_stats.date_hour': '2018-08-26 13'}):
    mycollection.update_one({'area': 'zone 45', 'Report_stats.date_hour': '2018-08-26 13'},
                                    {
                                    '$inc': {
                                        'Report_stats.$.count': 1
                                        },
                                    '$set': {
                                        'last_state': 'Clear'
                                        },
                                    '$push': {
                                        'recent_indices': 33,
                                        }
                                    },
                     )
else:
    mycollection.update_one({'area': 'zone 45'},
                                     {
                                     '$set': {
                                         'last_state': 'Clear'
                                         },
                                     '$push': {
                                         'recent_indices': 33,
                                         'Report_stats':{'date_hour':'2018-08-26 13', 'count':1}
                                         }
                                     },
                                     upsert = True
                     )
```

However, it still is performing one query twice to update one document based on one request, which is not quite satisfactory.

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What if I figured out from your above reply is that if *`Report_stats.date_hour exists in your document, then you increment the counter or else you just push a new document.`*

I believe we can do it using **$cond or $switch**. Can you please take a look.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond

Meanwhile, I am trying to write the whole query for you and lets see if it works.

Thanks, Kanika

Comment: Thanks, and yes you got it right, but it seems that $cond and $switch are used in aggregation, so I'm not sure how they can be used in an update query. 
Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Instead of find query, you can use aggregate and then you can use just update_one(...) instead of doing it in "if and else".

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll be looking into it. However if you had the time to write the query as you said, that would be much appreciated.